# How detect distance from first and second detected lane - Hough transform (OpenCV)

Tags: java, android, opencv

with Hough Transform (OpenCV) detect lanes

```
//do Hough transform to find lanes
Imgproc.HoughLinesP(thresholdImage, lines, rho, theta, threshold,   VActivity.HOUGH_MIN_LINE_LENGTH, VActivity.HOUGH_MAX_LINE_GAP);
for (int x = 0; x < lines.cols(); x++)
{
    double[] vec = lines.get(0, x);
    double x1 = vec[0],
    y1 = vec[1],
    x2 = vec[2],
    y2 = vec[3];
    Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
    Point end = new Point(x2, y2);

    double dx = x2 - x1;
    double dy = y2 - y1;
    double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI;
    Log.i(VActivity.TAG, Double.toString(angle));

    if (Math.abs(angle) <= VActivity.LINE_REJECT_DEGREES)
    {
        Log.i(VActivity.TAG, "Reject: " + Double.toString(angle));
        // reject near horizontal lines
        continue;
    }
    Core.line(mRgba, start, end, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
}
```

At code result i have 4 lines x1, x2, y1, y2, but sometimes algorithm don't detect lanes and need save in some hash table detected lanes or something else?

```
Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
Point end = new Point(x2, y2);
```

What do you think about?
I need to find distance from first lane to second to remind user for crossing the one line to another line...

Comment: Distance between your two Point objects? `double distance = start.distance(end);`

Comment: for example we have first lane, second (null), third detect and another null, and something else, but if we don't detect second lane we need save somewhere results and try calculate distance. But it's good idea?

Comment: Distance between your two Point objects? It's just coordinates x,y - start points and x, y - end points

Comment: If you need to detect null, use `if(blah != null)`